# Invoke External web service with WSDL file using camel in Java Dsl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-camel, cxf

I am new to camel and when i was looking at the examples i found this :

```
<from uri="file:src/data?noop=true"/>
        <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="&gt;&gt;&gt; ${body}"/>
        <to uri="cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdlURL=src/main/resources/META-INF/stockquote.wsdl&amp;serviceName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}StockQuote&amp;portName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}StockQuoteSoap&amp;dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
        <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="&gt;&gt;&gt; ${body}"/>
```

Inside the src/data folder i found two xml files. am not sure what exactly is happening. Directly call the webservice in the from component and log the response. The thing that am doing below is correct or how can i approach this java DSL ??

```
from("cxf: http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdlURL=src/main/resources/META-INF/stockquote.wsdl&amp;serviceName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}StockQuote&amp;portName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}StockQuoteSoap&amp;dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
.log("response is ${body}")
```

Guys please help...

Comment: Its actually not so hard to do migrate XML -> Java. Just do the same. from (file) . log . to (cxf) log.

Comment: Hi @ClausIbsen i am able to make it work in java dsl as well. am not able to understand what the code inside data folder is for and the payload section in CXF component...the code is :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetQuote xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
      <symbol>AAPL</symbol>
    </GetQuote>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>

Comment: Hi @ClausIbsen 

My code is : 
from("file://E:/testwebservice")
.log("Input received is ${body}")
.to("cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdlURL=src/main/resources/META-INF/stockquote.wsdl&serviceName=http://www.webserviceX.NET/StockQuote&portName=http://www.webserviceX.NET/StockQuoteSoap&dataFormat=MESSAGE")
.log("Body received is ${body}");
and i get the exception in wsdlURL 
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'src/main/resources/META-INF/stockquote.wsdl'

Answer (score -1):

I experienced that cxf component doesn't work in  tag.... it works well in  tag as given in example

Comment: I could not understand what you are saying. can u show me a example code for the above problem to call a external Web service with camel.